# bash script , sort on inconsistent date field

Tags: bash, shell, date, datetime

How can i sort a file when the date is inconsistent in the format? one of the steps in the script is to sort a file on date. Date format is inconsistent. for example: some times it would be mm//dd/yyyy and some times it would be m/d/yyyy.

below is the sort command:

```
sort -t"," -k4 -k5 -k11 -k2 -k3 $aval_oldtax_file > oldunix_scol.csv
```

below is the copy of input file:

```
1,12/01/2017 12:00:00 AM,12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM,0001,PC040206,Monroe,UNION,NC,28110-2712,US,County,179,UNION,Sales,NC COUNTY TAX,0.020000,0,0,,
1,8/1/2010 12:00:00 AM,12/01/2017 12:00:00 AM,0001,PC040206,Monroe,UNION,NC,28110-2712,US,County,179,UNION,Sales,NC COUNTY TAX,0.020000,0,0,,
1,12/01/2017 12:00:00 AM,12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM,0001,PC040206,Monroe,UNION,NC,28110-2712,US,Special,179,UNION,Sales,NC COUNTY TAX,0.020000,0,0,,
1,7/1/2011 12:00:00 AM,11/01/2017 12:00:00 AM,0001,PC040206,Monroe,UNION,NC,28110-2712,US,State,37,NORTH CAROLINA,Sales,NC STATE TAX,0.047500,0,0,,
1,11/01/2017 12:00:00 AM,12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM,0001,PC040206,Monroe,UNION,NC,28110-2712,US,State,37,NORTH CAROLINA,Sales,NC STATE TAX,0.057500,0,0,,
```

Answer (score 0):

decorate/sort/undecorate idiom, add a key by formatting the date in a sorting friendly format.

```
paste <(cut -d, -f2 file | xargs -I {} date -d {} +%F%T) file | sort | cut -f2-
```